# GCC, What's the effect of declaring visibility "default" and "hidden", from objdump perspective

Tags: gcc, elf

A very concrete question here. I have two sample `foo2d.c` files like this:

First,

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((visibility("default"))) void FooX(int i);

void Foo2(int i)
{
    printf("Via Foo2(%d)\n", i);
    FooX(i);
}
```

Second,

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) void FooX(int i);

void Foo2(int i)
{
    printf("Via Foo2(%d)\n", i);
    FooX(i);
}
```

The only difference is the visibility declaration of `FooX`.

Given the two files the same name and compile them twice(`gcc -c foo2d.c`), I got two .o files and rename them to be `foo-default.o` and `foo-hidden.o` respectively. I compare the two .o files and find out they differ by only one byte.

[image: Beyond Compare showing the diff]

I really want to know the meaning of the difference of this byte, from a relocatable object's perspective. Can objdump or readelf, or whatever standard tools tell the difference of them?

My experiment env is openSUSE Linux 11.4, gcc 4.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the difference should be in the symbol table. A symbol's visibility is determined from its st_other field of the symtab entry. It says:

```
Name          value
STV_DEFAULT   0
STV_INTERNAL  1
STV_HIDDEN    2
STV_PROTECTED 3
```

Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1386/6m7qcoblj/index.html#chapter7-27

Add: you can dump the symtab to check:

```
    readelf -x .symtab foo-hidden.o
    objdump -t foo-hidden.o
```